# how to find next date when PST switches to PDT next and vice versa

Tags: c++, winapi, datetime, timezone

My program runs on a Windows computer on which timezone is `not` PST/PDT. But it needs to operate according to PST/PDT time rules.

Wrt to summer/winter time, the program needs to know
the next date when PDT changes to PST or vice versa.
How  can I program in C++ finding the next summertime<->wintertime switch ?

Comment: You might want to edit the title: "PST switches to PDT" rather than "PST switches to EDT".

Comment: Having a quick search around using Google indicates that the only list available in Windows is stored in the registry. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244699/c-2-0-specific-timezone has some C# code to query the information you want, maybe you can port it to C++.

Answer (score 1):

Since the start and end of Daylight Savings Time have changed due to various acts of Congress, the information of the next savings transition is not fixed. I don't know if you need to reboot to apply DST changes, but if you do, you might want to update your estimate of the next transition more frequently than once.

The native API to get this information is [`GetTimeZoneInformationForYear`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb540851%28v=VS.85%29.aspx). You can pass in a specific time zone and year. That function fills out a `TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION` struct; the relevant information you want is `TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION::DaylightDate` and `TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION::StandardDate`

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Windows, use a C# class to do this and return the results to your C++ program via your interop of choice.  Otherise, you'll likely wind up rebuilding the .Net code that does this in C+, and in the process miss all the edge cases that .Net will handle for you.

You can use [TimeZoneInfo.Local](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.local.aspx) and then [get the adjustment rules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.getadjustmentrules.aspx) for it.

Answer (score 0):

Ugly brute force method:

Call `time(NULL)` to get the current time as a `time_t` value.

Use `localtime()` to convert this value to a `struct tm`.  (Consider adjusting the `tm_hour` member to 12, so you're checking noon every day.)

Repeatedly add 1 day to the `tm_day` member of your `struct tm`, then use `mktime()` to convert back to `time_t`.

Use `difftime()` to compare each incremented `time_t` value to the previous one.  When `difftime() gives you a value that's not close to 86400.0 (the number of seconds in 1 day), you've found a DST transition.  If you do this 365 times without finding a transition, something is wrong.

You can probably take some shortcuts if you're willing to make some assumptions about the representation of `time_t`.

Obviously this is only an outline of a solution -- and I haven't tried it myself.

And I've just re-read the question and realized that I've completely ignored the part where you said that the computer isn't on PST or PDT.  (Can you set the timezone for the program?)